# Callback Firing Too Early when External File Accessed

Tags: xml, callback

I am trying to parse a simple XML file,

```
<gallery>
    <photo><file>Image1</file></photo>
    <photo><file>Image2</file></photo>
    <photo><file>Image3</file></photo>
<gallery>
```

then execute a callback function.  The parsing works fine, but I cannot get the callback to fire after the parse.  I am trying to obtain

```
Image1
Image2
Image3
Done!
```

but Done! is always being output before the images can be listed.  Why is this?  Here is my Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var imgArray=[];

    function xmlparse(callback){
    $.get("gallery.xml",{},function(xml){
    $('photo',xml).each(function(i){
        file = $(this).find("file").text();
        (imgArray).push(file);
            $('.content').append(imgArray[i] + '<br>'); 
        i++;
    });
    });
    if(typeof callback == "function") callback();
    };

    xmlparse(function(){
    $('.content').append('Done! <br>');
});
});
```

Is a delay timer necessary or are there ways to use .done, .resolve, and so forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work, also take a look at the resolve() function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

var imgArray=[];
function xmlparse(){
$.get("gallery.xml",{},function(xml){
     $('photo',xml).each(function(i){
        file = $(this).find("file").text();
         (imgArray).push(file);
         $('.content').append(imgArray[i] + '<br>'); 
         i++;
     }).promise().done( function(){ 
            $('.content').append('Done! <br>'); });
     });

xmlparse();

});
```

best

M

Comment: Mboeckle, you are the freakin' man.  My Smashing jQuery book doesn't get this advanced, and I thought .promise was just for animation.  Thanks mucho!  Though I am still curious... if xmlparse() wasn't a parser but an internal function, my callback worked.  Is it because of the delay having to access another file?

Comment: Yes please accept the answer -  you load the file through $get and just attach .promise to the $each loop; try adding .done to the $get should work to or . complete (also if its not successfull but done) you can add the each loop there inside