# XML parse - What should promise act on?

Tags: xml, parsing, promise

I got some help using .promise().done on an xml parser, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215551/callback-firing-too-early-when-external-file-accessed). This method is fine if you combine the .promise().done() with the parser function.  What I really wanted to do, though, was define the parser function separately up top, then execute it later in the code, and the apply the promise().done() to it there:

```
var xmlparse = function(){
  $.get("file.xml), {}. function(xml) {
     $('photo',xml).each(function(i){
       ...
       array filling
       .....
      });
   });
});

xmlparse().promise().done(function(){...
```

I've learned that line above doesn't work; I need to pass an object that the original function acted on.  If xmlparse() was changing a div, for example, I'd say $('div').promise().done().  But what exactly can being passed for an XML parser that doesn't change any HTML structure?  (This goes back to the original solution; I'm glad it works, but I don't understand quite why.)  Any help's appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to chain things with promises is `.then`, we can [compose this ourselves on top of a callback API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) but we don't have to in this case since `$.get` already returns a promise.

The point of promises is to give us back desirable properties (like returning and throwing) of synchronous code, the way to chain operations is via the `.then` mwrhos.

```
var xmlparse = function(){
  // we return a promise here
  return $.get("file.xml).then(function(xml) { // .then is used to continue
     $('photo',xml).each(function(i){
       ...
       array filling
       .....
      });
      return array; // returning from a `.then` will cause it to be the return value of 
      // the whole promise chain, promises compose. 
   });
};
```

Now, our `xmlparse` is a promise returning function so we can do:

```
xmlparse().done(function(result){...
    // access result here
});
```

If we want to chain it to other asynchronous operations we can change `.then` to `.then` and chain on.

Comment: Well, that explains this case.  I bookmarked the link you provided to help me understand more.  Thanks, Ben!

Comment: Glad I could help, good luck. I strongly recommend a better promise implementation, jQuery's are kind of bad.